# Auto formatting datagridview's cell on when cell is left

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Hello I'm wondering how to format cell for 2 decimal positions everytime there is made some change. But I need to format only exact column so I thought that this might work:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   dataGridView1.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "n2";
}
```

But it doesn't format the cell. Why?

Comment: which kind of format you are willing to implement

Comment: @Anand Currency like 2 decimal positions.

Comment: @Marek what's the data type of `dataGridView.Columns[2]`? It should be numeric such as `float`, `int`, ...

Comment: @KingKing I load the data from SQL as as decimal(12,2) for example when I write 120 and leave I would like to have 120.00

Comment: @Marek are you sure the `CellLeave` event handler was already registered correctly? You can try setting some break point in its code and run to check it.

Comment: @Marek: Have you solve already your problem? Have you tried out the solution provided as answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `ValueType` property in order to format it properly because by default it is a `String` data type. Say you want to make it `Decimal` data type then you will have the following.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  dataGridView1.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
  dataGridView1.Columns[2].ValueType = typeof(Decimal);
}
```

Comment: It's still not clear whether the OP uses `DataBound` or not, when using `DataBound`, the `ValueType` is determined by the underlying `DataSource`.

Comment: @KingKing I agree with you but I tested this with an underlying `DataSource` from an `MS-SQL Database` using `Decimal(18,5)` as data type to be exact and it works.

Comment: @Edper I'm sorry but it doesn't format the number from e.g. 20 to 20.00 when I press enter on the cell. But thank you so much for your time. In case you are interested in solving another issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933955/select-item-in-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn-loaded-from-sql Kindest regards to you.

Comment: @Marek: I tried it in my own computer and it works. I just don't know why it does not work for you.

Comment: @Edper I'm so sorry I made mistake in indexing the column. Your code works awesome!

Comment: Great to know that @Marek. Happy coding and GOD bless. I'll try to take a peek at your other problem later when I have the time.

Answer (score 1):

try it ..

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value=double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString()).ToString("F",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)